# French character validation in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, validation, special-characters

I am developing a web application for a french client. Now am really confused about the french character validation in PHP and Javascript too.

I would like to allow alphanumeric and special characters : é è ê î ï ô à ç , . #.

This is the PHP code I am using for alphanumeric and normal character validation

```
$aValid = array(' ', ' ','   ','    ','     ','-','.',',','#');
    if(!ctype_alnum(str_replace($aValid, '', $str))) {
        return false;
    } 
    else
        return true;
```

Please help me to include the validation of special characters : é è ê î ï ô à ç , . # in this code. I am also confused about the validation in javascript too. It is UTF-8 encoded so can I directly use the special characters in it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) for such tasks:

```
return preg_match("/^[a-z\déèêîïôàç,.#]+$/ui", $str);
```

Comment: don't forget to add the a-zA-Z0-9 class in your interval as he wants alpha num chars.

Comment: Thanks for your time Deele, my doubt is that ' Can I use the special characters directly in the code ?', as I said I am using an array of characters for validation in php.

Comment: @artragis ofcourse, it was just for concept at first, as it looked like author don't know regex at all.

Comment: @Technosavia if you use "u" flag, it will run regex in UTF-8 mode. Additionally, save/convert your php file in UTF-8 (without BOM) mode, and you can use whatever UTF charecters inside, you like. Just match HTML head charset to your file encodings.